# Setting buffer size for FTDI using python in Raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, uart, ftdi

I'm trying to set a serial buffer size for RX and TX using python in raspberry pi with the FDTI driver. The following code is shown below:

```
ser.set_buffer_size(rx_size = 250000, tx_size = 65536)
```

This line is causing an attribute error in python. However, I can't transmit or receive the data using FTDI from the kernel without setting a buffer size. My question is, how can I assign a buffer size to send and receive the data in raspberry pi using python with FTDI?

Thank you in advance for your valuable suggestion.
**DAP**

Comment: Can you post the error in denial. Also mention driver details and IC details. `set_buffer_size : Recommend a buffer size to the driver (device driver can ignore this value). Must be called after the port is opened.`.
Most probably the driver will ignore this value.

Comment: Yes, previously I commented the buffer size and the driver also opened the serial port communication like you said in the comment. I'm not able to send and receive the data using serial port communication. I also tried to use GPIO of raspberry but I couldn't succeed with this strategy.

Comment: Post your program. Post error if any.

Comment: There is no error, But couldn't are to send or receive the data to the kernel.

Comment: Can you post your code along with IC details.

Comment: I solved my issuse. It is a loose connection between FTDI and the raspberry USB port. Thank you very much for your efforts....!